# T-SQL Global / Shared Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When writing TSQL stored procedures I find myself wanting to centralize / normalize some parts of the code. For example, if I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn IN (2, 4, 8)
```

For cases like this I would like to put (2,4,8) in some place outside of the procedure that I could reuse in some other query later -- to avoid repetition. Is there a built-in way to do this? What would really neat is if I could break apart entire pieces of SQL code, like parts of the WHERE clause, and reuse those in other queries, but I doubt this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often wanted a similar thing but that specifically does not exist.  Here are a couple of things you *can* do.

**Option 1**

What we have done is used User Defined Functions (UDF) to gather what you might call global variables.

You're able to call a UDF inline within your query which makes it really useful.

Suppose you wanted to specify a server name which you'd use across multiple stored procedures.  Duplicating that value wouldn't be optimally maintainable.  Instead you might do something like:

```
select * from clientNodes where serverName = dbo.SOME_SERVER_NAME()
```

**Option 2**

This one is more obvious but worth pointing out.  Keep your values in a lookup table and reference it by an ID.  The ID wouldn't change but the value it refers to might.  Using the sample example as above but for this option:

```
Table: Servers
Columns: ServerID, ServerName

declare @serverName varchar(50)
select @serverName = ServerName from Servers where ServerID = 1
```

This is a typical approach to database normalization but people don't necessarily think about this for purposes of keeping DB-logic data centralized.

I hope that helps!
Ian

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2005, you could consider using a table-valued function.

E.g.:

```
SELECT ... FROM SomeTable INNER JOIN SomeFunction() F ON SomeTable.SomeColumn = F.Id

...

CREATE FUNCTION SomeFunction()
RETURNS @IdTable TABLE (Id INT)
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT 2 Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8
)
```

More commonly, you might want to pass in the values as an argument to a stored procedure. You could do this as a comma-separated string. E.g.

```
EXEC MyProcedure('2,4,8')

...

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
(
   @IdString AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ... FROM SomeTable INNER JOIN SomeFunction(@IdString) F ON SomeTable.SomeColumn = F.Id
END

...

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeFunction
(
  @IdString VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @IdTable TABLE (Id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CommaIndex INT, @TotalLength INT, @StartIndex INT, @Id VARCHAR(10)
    SET @TotalLength=LEN(@IdString)
    SET @StartIndex = 1

    WHILE @StartIndex <= @TotalLength
    BEGIN
        SET @CommaIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @IdString, @StartIndex)
        IF @CommaIndex > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Id = SUBSTRING(@IdString, @StartIndex, @CommaIndex-@StartIndex)
            SET @StartIndex = @CommaIndex + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            Set @Id = SUBSTRING(@IdString, @StartIndex, @TotalLength-@StartIndex+1)
            SET @StartIndex = @TotalLength+1
        END
        INSERT INTO @IdTable
        (Id)
        VALUES
        (CAST(@Id AS INT))
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You would usually create a **VIEW** for what you are trying to accomplish.

First create a function that returns SomeColumn values 2, 4, 8

```
create function fnSomeTableFilters()
returns @Result table ( ID int not null )
as

begin
    insert  @Result(ID)
    select 2
    union select 4
    union select 8

    return
end
GO
```

Now Create a View that filters 2,4,8

```
create view vwFilteredSomeTable
as
select * from SomeTable where SomeColumn in (select ID from dbo.fnSomeTableFilters())
```

Last, your query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM vwFilteredSomeTable
```

Make sure to give your view a meaningful name

e.g) I have a view called vwActiveSites for to query against Active sites as name suggests

```
create view vwActiveSites
as
    select  ...
    from    Sites S
    where   S.Active = 1
```

The beauty here is that, all your queries that uses **vwFilteredSomeTable** does not need to change.  If you need to filter with different value, only *fnSomeTableFilters* need be changed

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - use a table or a view. SomeColumn being IN (2, 4, 8) must be meaningful to your data somehow, so model it that way. Give it a meaningful name, and you can reuse it by itself or JOINed to other queries. Why bury it in a UDF or some such?

Eg., if SomeColumn was State and the values ('FL', 'GA', 'SC') were your South Eastern Territories, then instead of spreading:

```
 SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE State IN ('FL', 'GA', 'SC')
```

all around, just create a Territory column and be done with it.

Repeated use of a static WHERE clause is another table or attribute (aka a concept) just begging to come out.